# Importing shared frontend/backend code into storybook. Unexpected character @, webpack issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, storybook, javascript-decorators

I have a yarn monorepo with 4 folders.

```
/frontend - frontend CRA app.
/ui-components - Storybook project, using storybook v6 and webpack5.
/backend - backend Node.JS express app.
/shared - shared code between frontend and backend.
```

`/shared` folder contains some models that use decorators, e.g

```js
@Model('user')
class User {
  id: string;
}
```

I have added /shared code into storybook via link in /ui-components/package.json

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@lib/shared": "link:../shared",
    ...
```

But then when rendering and doing `const user = new User()` in that story I get following error:

```
nexpected error while loading ./stories/user-avatar.stories.tsx: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (28:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../../../node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
> @Model('user')
```

I've spent days on this and I am completely at loss here whether it's webpack5 or storybook issue.

Comment: Are you importing the built code  from `shared` directory or you just importing the Javascript files? I mean can your `ui-components` handle decorators?

Comment: I am just importing files e.g in my storybook component, e.g 
`import { User } from '@lib/shared/models'; const user = new User();`
This was my thought too and I set
 `"experimentalDecorators": true` in `/ui-components/ts-config.json`